# implementing Extend and Include Play framwork

Tags: playframework-2.0

Im trying  to implement templating  by using this referance 
http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/JavaTemplateUseCases

but for reason i cant    understand how all the inheritances between  files  working

im trying to reuse an html code

this is the sidebar.html file:

```
<h3>abc </h3>
 <a href=#" class="btn btn-info"> blabla</a>
```

this is the main.scala.html file

```
@(title: String)(sidebar: Html)
 <html>
<head>
<title>@title</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="side">
@sidebar
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and this is the index.scala.html file :

```
@main("Home") {
<h1>Sidebar</h1>

}
```

thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want to use the `sidebar` template in the `index` template?

If so, you're very close:

First change the name of `sidebar.html` to `sidebar.scala.html` (even though it doesn't have any scala code in it, this will be just fine).

Then, you can call this template in your index template like this:

```
@sidebar()
```

So index.scala.html looks like this:

```
@main("Home) {

    <h1>Sidebar</h1>
    @sidebar()

}
```